# Geolocation API in IE11

Tags: geolocation, internet-explorer-11

I'm attempting to use HTML5 Geolocation on IE11, but despite allowing location permission, I get an error, "This site does not have permission to use the Geolocation API."

To replicate:

1. Open any site in IE11 (I'm user browerstack to emulate a Windows 10)
2. Copy/paste the following code in the console:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: false,
  timeout: 1000000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('got your position');
}

function error(err) {
  console.log(err);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

3. Click "Allow Once" when the location prompt appears
4. Observe the [Resulting Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LCPG.png), `"This site does not have permission to use the Geolocation API."`

My browserstack is running IE11 version 11.1.17134.0, on a Windows 10.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in IE 11. I think that's because IE doesn't support [Secure context required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation#browser_compatibility). Geolocation  is available only in secure contexts. Besides, IE 11 is going to retire, I suggest that you can use a modern browser as instead.

Comment: I just tried - https://maps.google.com - on Win 10 IE 11 combination on BrowserStack and encountered a similar message. Seems like some restrictions have been enabled on the IE browser available on BrowserStack.